# I can't install llama-index on kaggle. It seems i don't have connexion but i do

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, resolution, redirection

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7eb9f80ca0e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/llama-index/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7eb9f80ca3e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/llama-index/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7eb9f80ca680>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/llama-index/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7eb9f80ca830>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/llama-index/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7eb9f80ca9e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/llama-index/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement llama_index==0.10.9 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for llama_index==0.10.9

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.